# Add item to python dictionary if the bool(item) is True

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to add an item to a dictionary only if the bool(item) evaluates to True:

```
if item_to_add:
    d["name_of_item"] = item_to_add
```

Is there a way to do this in 1 line? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care about doing it in one line?

Comment: I have to repeat the lines like above many times and I was wondering if there was a way to shorten the code (or number of lines)

Comment: If you have many of such lines, you should rather think about how to put them in a loop, than shrinking the code for each copy&pasted line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
if item_to_add: d["name_of_item"] = item_to_add
```

Comment: Wow never knew such syntax thanks! (will mark as answer in 15 min)